# Bash: How to evaluate this string?

Tags: string, bash, echo, eval, evaluation

If I write

```
echo --optionA hello --optionB `seq 1 2 10` --optionC `printf "happy %.0s" {1..3}`
```

it gets evaluated as

```
--optionA hello --optionB 1 3 5 7 9 --optionC happy happy happy
```

This is the *desired string*, which I could eventually store in a new variable with

```
desiredString=$(echo --optionA hello --optionB `seq 1 2 10` --optionC `printf "happy %.0s" {1..3}`)
```

If I start with the string to evaluate saved in a string as

```
string='--optionA hello --optionB `seq 1 2 10` --optionC `printf "happy %.0s" {1..3}`'
```

then, how can I get the desired string? Here are some naïve attempts

```
$ echo $string
--optionA hello --optionB `seq 1 2 10` --optionC `printf "happy %.0s" {1..3}`

$ eval "$string"
-bash: eval: --: invalid option
eval: usage: eval [arg ...]

$ echo `echo $string`
--optionA hello --optionB `seq 1 2 10` --optionC `printf "happy %.0s" {1..3}`
```

---

I am using GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to pass arguments into an external command and this `echo` is just an example. Check if it's possible to use [functions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) to do what you want, since Kamil's post about potential vulnerabilities is right on the money.

Answer (score 2):

As your answer is ok and feel free to accept it, let's make it better.

The following:

```
 string="-e string"
 eval "echo $string"
```

will print only `string` without the `-e`, as the `-e` is interpreted as echo argument.

To make it worse, strings like `string='; rm -rf /'` will execute the rm command and wipe your harddrive. A better and idiomatic approach would be to properly escaped `printf`:

```
eval "printf '%s' \"$string\""
```

@edit

After re-reading your question I think you are just searching for:

```
string="--optionA hello --optionB `seq 1 2 10` --optionC `printf "happy %.0s" {1..3}`"
```

or as backticks ` are deprecated:

```
string="--optionA hello --optionB $(seq 1 2 10) --optionC $(printf "happy %.0s" {1..3})"
```

Using `var=$(echo ....)` in most cases is just the same as `var="..."`.

Answer (score 1):

I got it 2 minutes after posting the question...

```
$ eval "echo $string"
--optionA hello --optionB 1 3 5 7 9 --optionC happy happy happy
```